# Why was question closed/deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question a while ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870640/qttreepropertybrowser-way-to-lock-property-but-still-have-it-selectable

It's apparently been "deleted for reasons of moderation" - but I never got notified of it being closed/downvoted - so I'm a bit confused as to what happened.

If someone with the necessary reputation level could look at it and tell me what happened? I just want to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was deleted by automated process back in May 5<sup>th</sup> as it got no answers and no upvotes for a year and didn't have enough views or comments to "justify" keeping it around.

Here is the official post where it was implemented:

[Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Comment: Thank you, Sha. I was getting a little confused wondering how it met the criteria for being a bad question.

Comment: @TZHX not a bad question, more like abandoned question.

Comment: not really abandonned, it just never got any answers so I moved on with life (and got a different job). I'll accept this when the system lets me.

Comment: If you want to re-ask the question let me know, I can copy&paste it here for your sake - maybe now you can ask it better in a form that will attract more attention to it. :)